# How to execute code before @InitBinder validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a program that has a functionality to upload a file and then validate if it's name format is correct and save it to db.

In my main controller I am using @InitBinder for validation.

```
@InitBinder("uploadFileForm")
    protected void initBinderUploadForm(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(fileNameFormatValidator);
    }
```

In my validator method I am using this code snippet:

```
static void validateFileName(String fileUploadKey, MultipartFile file, Errors errors) {
        Matcher validFilenameMatcher = VALID_FILE_NAME.matcher(file.getOriginalFilename());
        if (!validFilenameMatcher.matches()) {
            errors.rejectValue(fileUploadKey, null, null, SOME_REGEX);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is, I want to format file name (like replacing some characters in file name) and then use validator class. Thus I need to change file name before the validation.

How can I achieve editing file name before validating the format with **@InitBinder**?

Edit: Noone answers? Or the question isn't clear ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `WebDataBinder`'s [addCustomFormatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#addCustomFormatter-org.springframework.format.Formatter-) like you did for adding a validator ?

```
@InitBinder("uploadFileForm")
protected void initBinderUploadForm(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(fileNameFormatter); 
    binder.setValidator(fileNameFormatValidator);
}
```

Comment: nice. but if I use addCustomFormatter then how can I edit format name ? I mean: for validation it is not changing anything just check and throw exception, where as if I do some change like name = name + '2' how can I change the file name like a static variable or etc..

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Create your own fileFormatter with a Multipart generic type, that way you will override the parse method and return a new file with the desired name. Didn't test it on files before only on domain object so let me know if it works for you